# Opening comment context menu on site with no account crashes Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When viewing a question on a Stack Exchange site that I do not have an account on, then tapping on a comment to get the View Profile/Vote up/Flag menu will result in the app crashing. I'd expect it to open a menu with View Profile as the only option.

<sup>using v0.1.81</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in version 0.1.82 which came out last night :)

Comment: Look at that efficiency! The Play Store decided to stop auto updating things... Did you remove the "Log out" button from the slide out drawer in 0.1.82?

Comment: It's now in the settings page per feedback from the Google Play team.

Comment: Ah. The _only_ place I didn't look before commenting. By the way, props on making 82 alpha releases! It's come a long way. Hope you get some sort of party at 0.1.100. Then when it's actually released.

Comment: I hope it's a Magic the Gathering party.